# Populating an array in the results object with MyBatis

Tags: kotlin, mybatis, spring-mybatis

What is the recommended approach for populating an array with values from a column in the SQL result when using MyBatis?

I have the following code which is working but I need the response to be collapsed into a single object that contains all the appointment IDs.

**Record**

```
@Serializable
data class SiteSchedule(
    val id: String,
    @Serializable(with = LocalDateSerializer::class) val date: LocalDate,
    val appointmentId: String
)
```

**Mapper**

```
@Mapper
interface SiteScheduleMapper {

  @Select(
      """
      select schedule.id, schedule.date, appointment.id
      from schedule, appointment
      where schedule.date = #{date}
      and appointment.schedule_id = schedule.id
      and appointment.status = 'S'
      """)
  fun findSchedule(
      @Param("date") date: LocalDate
  ): Array<SiteSchedule>
}
```

**SQL Query Result**

| id | date | appointmentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 300 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 400 |

**Current API Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "dateTime": "2021-07-01",
    "appointmentId": "100"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "dateTime": "2021-07-01",
    "appointmentId": "200"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "dateTime": "2021-07-01",
    "appointmentId": "300"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": "2021-07-01",
    "appointmentId": "400"
  }
]
```

**Desired API Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": "2021-07-01",
    "appointmentIds": ["100","200","300","400"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Use a `<collection>` tag. See https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Advanced_Result_Maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating an XML mapper that defined a `collection` property in the result map:

**SiteScheduleMapper.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.domain.mappers.SiteScheduleMapper">
    <resultMap id="siteScheduleResultMap" type="com.domain.SiteSchedule">
        <id column="sch_id" property="scheduleId" />
        <result column="appt_dt" property="date" />
        <collection property="appointmentIds" ofType="String">
            <result column="appt_id" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

**Record**

```
@Serializable
data class SiteSchedule
constructor(
    val id: String? = "",
    @Serializable(with = LocalDateSerializer::class) val date: LocalDate? = null,
    val appointmentIds: MutableList<String>? = mutableListOf()
)
```

**Mapper interface**

```
@Mapper
interface SiteScheduleMapper {

  @Select(
      """
      select schedule.id, schedule.date, appointment.id
      from schedule, appointment
      where schedule.date = #{date}
      and appointment.schedule_id = schedule.id
      and appointment.status = 'S'
      """)
  @ResultMap("siteScheduleResultMap")
  fun findSchedule(
      @Param("date") date: LocalDate
  ): Array<SiteSchedule>
}
```